# Upload File to AWS S3 with Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, amazon-s3

I have an external application uploading a file to my rails web app. (Developed on Heroku, but that's not completely relevant)

I need to upload that file to AWS.  I've successfully connected to AWS with rails, but I can't figure out how to access the file that was uploaded.

I know I need to do `File.open({path to file})`, then pass the File to AWS

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I forgot to set the multipart enctype in my test external application...if anyone else has this same problem this code should work:

```
AWS::S3::S3Object.store('{filename.ext_for_aws}',params[:{name_from_post}],'{bucket}')
```